# Cant sort my NSMutable array

Tags: ios, sorting, nsmutablearray, alphabetical

So I use the following to alphabetically sort my NSMutableArray and it works great.

```
[myArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

But this is doing something to my array as I can't add to it after it crashes after the following line

```
[myArray addObject:textBox.text];
```

I get the following error

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray insertObject:atIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'
```

I know it has something do with the sorting function as this problem only occurs when I modify my mutable array! Can anyone understand why this is happening?

Not sure why its saying its an immutable object definitely a mutableArray I'm working with..

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *myArray;
```

Heres the rest of the code

```
@synthesize myArray;

myArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"numberOne",@"numberTwo",@"numberThree",@"numberFour",@"numberFive", nil];
```

NSUserDefault code

```
myUserDefault = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
myArray = [myUserDefault objectForKey:@"stuff"];
[myUserDefault synchronize];
```

Comment: Show the code where you actually create the array.

Comment: Post the full version of the code including how you initialize speciesArray that will give clues since right now basically the error message is saying myArray is an NSArray not an NSMutableArray. Not NSArray also has sortUsingSelector and it returns the sorted array. You should make sure the myArray is actually an NSMutableArray and not an NSArray

Comment: Can you show the line of code where you initialise the property?

Comment: There's nothing in the code you posted that should convert a mutable array to an immutable one. Are you doing something else with this array between when you sort it, and when you try to add the object?

Comment: @rdelmar im reloading a picker view thats all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> @property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *speciesArray;
> ```

See my answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22748539/341994

And indeed, the facts are exactly the same. It is not enough to *declare* the class of something. That thing must actually *be* that class (polymorphism). An instance *has* a class (as an internal fact about it), quite without regard for how you may cast or declare a variable that merely refers to it.

You will thus find that, however you are actually making or obtaining this array, it is a *non*-mutable array (NSArray); merely claiming it is mutable, as you are doing, will not make it so. The facts have a power of their own.

EDIT: And so indeed it proved to be the case. You are say, in effect, this:

```
myArray = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"stuff"];
```

Now `myArray` is an immutable array, *no matter how you declared `myArray`*. The fix is to do a `mutableCopy`:

```
myArray = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"stuff"] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: so your saying I have to create a class subclassing NSMutableArray?

Comment: I'm saying you have to create or obtain, somehow, an NSMutableArray - and that you are not currently doing so. I know this because the error says so: `-[__NSCFArray insertObject:atIndex:]` means you are at that moment talking to an __NSCFArray, which is part of the NSArray class cluster. If `myArray` is mutable when you say `sortUsingSelector:` but immutable when you say `insertObject:atIndex:` (or whatever), then something has happened to change it. Maybe you said `copy`. Maybe you made a whole new object. I don't know; you have not shown enough code.

Comment: By the way, it is rather odd that you said earlier that this was called `speciesArray` and then changed it. This makes me think there is something about your code that you are not reporting accurately. _Just copy and paste_. Do not mess with your code. Show us the _actual_ code, and show us _enough_ of it, not just little pieces here and there.

Comment: Also the fact that you are saying `myArray` and not `self.myArray` is suspicious. In modern Xcode that would not work. So maybe `myArray` is a _different_ variable - a local variable. Maybe you have two different arrays and you are confused about which one you are talking to. Again, hard to say; you are concealing the facts.

Comment: myArray is synthesized though... @synthesize myArray;

Comment: Okay, thanks, that explains that. So ignore what I said about that! If you omitted `@synthesize` (and let autosynthesis happen), then the instance variable would be `_myArray` and pure `myArray` would be illegal (which is cool).

Comment: would it have anything to do with this code actually(posting up top now)? I pull my mutable array from a nsuserdefault I'm loading it into my mutableArray though

Comment: Yep, that would be it. When it comes out of NSUserDefaults it is immutable. Call `mutableCopy` to make it mutable again!

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for bringing that up so late

Comment: No problem! In the end you tracked it down! Well done.

Comment: Sorry to persist, but I want to stress the lesson learned here. (1) Believe the runtime; it knows more than you do. Your statement "Not sure why its saying its an immutable object definitely a mutableArray I'm working with" was the exact wrong attitude to take. (2) Assume less; your original statement "I know it has something do with the sorting function" was just jumping to conclusions. Programming requires a kind of openness, and making assumptions or jumping to conclusions will blind you to other possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

when use `NSUserDefaults`, return array should be `NSArray`, not `NSMutableArray`:

```
myUserDefault = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[myUserDefault objectForKey:@"stuff"]];
[myUserDefault synchronize];
```